# GCC Linker undefined references

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I got a bunch of Netbeans managed C++ projects, and the following scenario:

1. *S1*: development system

   - Ubuntu 16.10 x64
   - **gcc 6.2.0**
2. *S2*: deployment system

   - CentOS 7 x64
   - **gcc 4.8.5**

There are the following projects:

- `libhls-kernel`, c++ shared object
- `hls_tester`, c++ console application

Netbeans configurations (*i.e.* Makefiles) are git-tracked and **equal** between *S1* and *S2*.

However, build in *S2* fails during link time with lots of similar errors, among which I choosed the following as a meaningful warning:

> ../../../libhls/Debug/GNU-Linux/libhls-kernel.so: undefined reference to `hls::AstrContainer::_interlace_cubes()'

Actual command is

```
gcc -m64 \
-o ../../dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/hls_tester build/Debug/GNU-Linux/hls_tester.o \
-L../../../libhls/Debug/GNU-Linux -L../../dist/Debug/GNU-Linux \
-Wl,-rpath,../../libhls/Debug/GNU-Linux -Wl,-rpath,../dist/Debug/GNU-Linux \
-lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_system -lhls-kernel -Wl,--as-needed
```

It seems that my `hls-kernel` library is build somehow wrong.

On *S2* I type

```
nm Debug/GNU-Linux/libhls-kernel.so | grep "interlace_cubes"
```

Obtaining

> U _ZN8hls13AstrContainerINS_14CubeDataSyncedEE16_interlace_cubesEv
>
> U _ZN8hls13AstrContainerINS_5algs19AlgorithmEE16_interlace_cubesEv
>
> U _ZN8hls13AstrContainerINS_9CubeImageEE16_interlace_cubesEv

The same `nm` command on *S1* returns

> 000000000008d320 W _ZN8hls13AstrContainerINS_14CubeDataSyncedEE16_interlace_cubesEv
>
> 000000000008cd50 W _ZN8hls13AstrContainerINS_16CubeDataUnsyncedEE16_interlace_cubesEv
>
> 000000000008de50 W _ZN8hls13AstrContainerINS_5algs19AlgorithmEE16_interlace_cubesEv
>
> 000000000008d880 W _ZN8hls13AstrContainerINS_9CubeImageEE16_interlace_cubesEv

Comment: "among which I choosed the following as MCVE" a warning is *not* a MCVE". A MCVE would be a minimal and compilable *code* example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Use `-C` option to `nm` to demangle C++ symbols.

Comment: Why are you linking C++ objects with `gcc` rather than `g++`?

Comment: Because my Netbeans-handled Makefile did so. Anyhow, output is equivalent with `g++`